# How to delete only a range of cells in a column in matlab

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a 23x5 cell array, and I'm trying to replace all cells but the first with an empty cell in one column.

When I try `array{2:end,4}=[]` I get "The right hand side of this assignment has too few values to satisfy the left hand side."

Still being confused with how Matlab handles different classes, I also tried 
`array(2:end,4)=[]` and get "A null assignment can have only one non-colon index."

I know a for loop could easily empty the contents of each cell, but I feel like there must be an easier solution to fix this.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "replace all cells but the first with an empty cell in one column" is not clear. Can you give a small, concrete example with input and output?

Comment: The first error is due to the fact that `[]` cannot be expanded into a multi-dimensional array of the size of the range you're replacing. This is illustrated by `test = repmat([], 2);`, for example, which will return `[]` and not a 2x2 array of `[]`. This will cause MATLAB to error out because that's not enough values to fill the range. The second error is a bit cryptic but it's because removing that chunk of data would result in an array that MATLAB cannot handle because it's not rectangular. With `array(2:end,4)=[]`, columns 1-3 and 5 would have 23 rows and column 4 would have 1.

Comment: Excaza, thanks very much for the explanation, the detail you've provided helps a lot with my understanding. And Luis Mendo, my apologies, I would provide an example but the post from jucestain below perfectly describes my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

`array(2:end,4) = {[]}`

For example:

```
>> array = cell(23,5);
>> array(:) = {1};
>> array(2:end,4) = {[]}
array = 

    [1]    [1]    [1]    [1]    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
    [1]    [1]    [1]     []    [1]
```

Comment: Note that this works because {[]} is a scalar (1x1) cell array, and in indexing `x(...) = s` where s is a scalar, s gets "scalar expanded" (i.e. replicated) to the same number of elements as `x(...)`.